# still unable to find google drive on the sidebar of mac

Tags: sidebar, google-apps

I still cannot find locate Google drive on my mac sidebar. I cannot find the google drive folder to drag and drop. When I click  next to my user, the drive does not appear.

Comment: stupid question from me...did you install it ? did you enable it in finders preferences ?

Answer (score 1):

Click the Google Drive icon in your menu bar.

Select "Open Google Drive folder"

Drag the icon from the top of that new window to your Sidebar.

Done.

[image]

Comment: Note that the consumer program was recently renamed "Google Backup and Sync" - if you don't see that app on your computer in the Applications folder, it isn't installed yet. Hit drive.google.com and download.